# Scalably add classes for instantiation in a jar

Tags: java, design-patterns, reflection, paradigms

I need some advice on a paradigm to follow. Before, I had something like this

`package/Instantiator.class`

`package/instances/GenericInstance.class (abstract)`

`package/instances/AInstance.class (extends Generic)`

`package/instances/BInstance.class (extends Generic)`

What `Instantiator` did was to search `package/instances` folder for all class files, and instantiated each with reflection and call an abstract method on all the instances and collected output and save to a DB.

Howver, I have to package my code in a Jar now, and Java does not seem to allow searching for all class files in a package in a jar (since it seems to mess with pathing).

I could add all instances in a List in GenericInstance or something, and then Instantiator could just get the list of classes.

But I would like for other people to just be able to add a class to that package and that's it.

What pattern should I follow here? Any code help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My method I just discovered:

```
try {    

    String jarName = new File(Insantiator.class.getProtectionDomain()    
                                                            .getCodeSource()    
                                                            .getLocation()    
                                                            .getPath())    
                                                            .getName();    
    JarFile jar = new JarFile(jarName);    
    Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jar.entries();    
    while(entries.hasMoreElements()) {    
        ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();    
        String name = entry.getName();    
        if(name.contains("package/instances") && !name.contains("GenericInstance.class") && name.contains(".class")) {    
            name = name.replace("/", ".").replace(".class", "");    
            try {    
                Class theClass = Class.forName(name);    
                GenericInstance instance = (GenericInstance ) theClass.newInstance();    
                instances.add(instance);    
            } catch(InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e) {    
                Utilities.writeLog("---- tried: " + name);    
                Utilities.writeLogException(null, e);    
            }    
        }    
    }        

} catch (IOException e) {    
    Utilities.writeLogException(null, e);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one builtin solution in the JDK, which is [`ServiceLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) (Java 6+). However, it requires that the user create a file in `META-INF/services` with a list of implementations.

If your base interface is `package.instances.GenericInstance` then your file would be called `META-INF/services/package.instances.GenericInstance` and its content would be:

```
path.to.implementation1
path.to.implementation2
```

etc. Depending on the build system you use, this kind of file may be generated for you automatically (maven has a plugin, see [here](https://github.com/francisdb/serviceloader-maven-plugin)).

> Java does not seem to allow searching for all class files in a package in a jar

Well yes it can (but the code to do it is quite complicated -- you have to create a `URLClassLoader` etc.).

One solution, if all jars are in your classpath at runtime, is to use something like [reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) (bonus: depends on Guava, so you get all of its niceties) which has efficient filters for classes etc, and can "reflect" classloaders other than the "system" classloader; so this could work too.

Comment: Thanks. It seems a found a simpler way. Seem my post.

Comment: Since you seem to use Java 7, it can be even simpler than that: have a look at [`FileSystems`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html), there is a provider for jar files ;)